How to change language for automatic spelling correction on iPhone?
I want my iOS to recognise both UK and US spellings as correct, but prioritise one over the other, depending on which is the primary language used (but that's secondary).
I came across solutions, notably this one: How can I change the language for automatic spelling correction? which could not be reproduced on an iPhone. It would still mark one of the spellings as incorrect.
I also came across a solution to force UK spelling, on the basis of which I tried to implement what I want, but was unsuccessful.
I think it's a matter of what version of English the keyboard is set to. Likewise, I could not find the “English” or “General English” option for keyboard language, which is something I sometime see on the web that reconciles both spellings.

On iOS, achieving a setup where both UK and US spellings are recognized as correct is a bit challenging because the system usually prioritizes one version of English over the other based on your primary language settings.

You can add frequently used words with their preferred spellings to your personal dictionary:
Go to Settings > General > Keyboard > Text Replacement.
Tap the + sign to add a new entry.
For instance, you can add “colour” with the shortcut being the same word, ensuring that it’s recognized as correct.

Consider using third-party keyboards like Gboard or SwiftKey which offer more flexible language settings and might provide better handling of multiple English variants.


You may also want to add both keyboards and switch between them if you often type in both languages.
